# How to pass model result to view in node js

Tags: node.js, express

I m new to node.js, try to making some small app.All is good but i m not able to pass model data outside the function:

Working Code is:

```
usermodel = require('../models/usermodel.js');
exports.index = function(req, res) {
var stuff_i_want = '';
 usermodel.userlist(req, function(result)
 {
    //stuff_i_want = result;
    res.render('index.ejs', {
                title: "Welcome to Socka | View Players",
                players:result
            });
    //rest of your code goes in here
 });
   console.log(stuff_i_want);


};
```

but i want some thing like:

```
usermodel = require('../models/usermodel.js');
exports.index = function(req, res) {
var stuff_i_want = '';
 usermodel.userlist(req, function(result)
 {
    stuff_i_want = result;

    //rest of your code goes in here
 });
   console.log(stuff_i_want);
    res.render('index.ejs', {
                title: "SA",
                players:result
            });


};
```

Comment: Tiny suggestion – try formatting your code a little bit cleaner and more consistently. Use the same number of spaces for indentation and 1 space in between pieces of code, e.g. `usermodel = require(...)`. If you post messy code, people won't think you care too much about a thoughtful answer.

Comment: It is not possible to execute something `async` (via callback) and get the result of that .userlist unless you wait for it.
What is the problem of having everything inside the callback  `function(result)
 {` ?

Comment: Problem is suppose i have multiple data to pass on view from different model, in that case which solution is work can you suggest me.@iwaduarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling an asynchronous function `userlist` that's why you need it inside the callback. You can use Promise libraries like [bluebirdjs](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) and refactor your usermodel implementation to standard nodejs function arguments `(err, result)`. In this case you can refactor it like the this below

```
const usermodel  = require('../models/usermodel.js');
exports.index = async function(req, res) {
 const players = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   usermodel.userlist(req, function(result){
     resolve(result)
   });
 })
 res.render('index.ejs', {
   title: "SA",
   players
 });


};
```